# How to document C# Cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell

I looked in the ms docs but couldn't find any suggestions on how to document a Cmdlet written in C# in a way that I can get the comments in PS via `Get-Help` or other commands.

I found some blog posts that point to [XmlDoc2CmdletDoc](https://github.com/red-gate/XmlDoc2CmdletDoc). I played a bit with it and it does the job but I find my code got a bit bulkier from the comments. Is this the way to go? I saw in the [Az](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell) repository that they use some external markdown files. What would be the appropriate direction?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.1 not sure if you would do the same for c#

Comment: I'm aware of how to document my PS cmdlets, but this question is about doing it in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(Compiled) cmdlets require *external* help files**, which must be represented in a "noisy", complex XML-based markup format called [MAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Assistance_Markup_Language)

- By contrast, [comment-based help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comment_Based_Help) is only supported in *written-in-PowerShell* cmdlets (a.k.a. [*advanced functions / scripts*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)).

The most convenient way to author such help files is via the **[`PlatyPS` module](https://github.com/PowerShell/platyPS)**, which **allows authoring topics in [*Markdown*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) format**.

While compiled cmdlets can act as PowerShell modules by themselves, it is preferable to package them as directory-based [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), which is indeed required if you want to include MAML help files (`*-Help.xml`).

Directory-based modules also allow you to include *conceptual* help topics, which, however, are mere *plain-text* files (`about_*.txt`).

Note that directory-based modules composed of written-in-PowerShell cmdlets too can opt to ship their help via MAML help files (and provide conceptual help topics), but using comment-based help is more convenient.